# How do I state that I want any number of types for an instance of a generic class in Python?

Tags: python, generics, python-typing

Let's say I wanted to create a generic class so that it can be used similarly to the following:

```
list[int]
list[int, float]
list[int, str]
```

If I am not mistaken, the first object represents a list of integers, the second object represents a list of either integers or floats, and the third object represents a list of either integers or strings.

How would I create a generic class  that allows for any number of types like the examples above in Python?

Comment: `list` takes exactly one type parameter: `list[int, str]` is invalid. That would be `list[int | str]` or `list[int] | list[str]`

Comment: @joel, so would `list[int | str]` specify that I want either a list of integers or a list of strings or a list of either integers or strings?

Comment: List of integers or strings.  List of entirely one or the other would be `list[int] | list[str]`

Comment: i'm not clear what you're trying to do but either `T = TypeVar("T")` with `list[T]` or `list[object]` come to mind. The latter is essentially useless so probably not that